# Migrating VMs from AWS to a Hyper-V based on-premise data center

Tags: amazon-ec2, hyper-v

Does any one know how to migrate an instance to a hyper v environment?

Normally we do migration from a virutal environment to cloud. But we do have a request from client to move the workloads from aws to physical data center.

We run Hyper-v on the physical environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VM Import/Export, Hyper-V is supported. The operations will be performed primarily through the aws-cli tool, there are some limitations included:

Exporting instances and volumes is subject to the following limitations:

```
You can't export an instance from Amazon EC2 unless you previously imported it into Amazon EC2 from another virtualization environment.

You must export your instances and volumes to one of the following image formats that your virtualization environment supports:

    Open Virtual Appliance (OVA), which is compatible with VMware vSphere versions 4, 5, and 6.

    Virtual Hard Disk (VHD), which is compatible with Citrix Xen and Microsoft Hyper-V virtualization products.

    Stream-optimized ESX Virtual Machine Disk (VMDK), which is compatible with VMware ESX and VMware vSphere versions 4, 5, and 6.

You can't export Amazon EBS data volumes.

You can't export an instance that has more than one virtual disk.

You can't export an instance that has more than one network interface.

You can't export an instance from Amazon EC2 if you've shared it from another AWS account.

You can't have more than five export tasks per region in progress at the same time.

VMs with volumes larger than 1 TiB are not supported.
```

Documentation where I got this information:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html